# matTooltipTouchGestures='off' also disables tooltips for non-touch gadgets

Tags: angular, angular-material, tooltip, touch

I want to disable some of my matTooltips (like those inside scrollable/draggable lists, ...). According to [API reference for Angular Material tooltip](https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/api) there is a suitable input property called

```
@Input('matTooltipTouchGestures')
touchGestures: TooltipTouchGestures
```

with `type TooltipTouchGestures = 'auto' | 'on' | 'off'`

But when I add the [matTooltipTouchGestures]="'off'" property to my tooltip item, then the tooltip becomes disabled for my non-touch gadgets as well, i.e.: no tooltip is shown when i hover the button with my mouse on desktop.

This is an example of how I applied the property:

```
<button (click)="myFunction()"
   mat-raised-button
   matTooltip="bla bla bla"
   [matTooltipTouchGestures]="'off'">
   <mat-icon>
       dashboard
   </mat-icon>
</button>
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to to add some dependent stuff:

```
// app.module.ts

import {MAT_TOOLTIP_SCROLL_STRATEGY_FACTORY_PROVIDER, MatTooltipModule} from "@angular/material/tooltip";
import {BrowserModule, HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG, HammerGestureConfig, HammerModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@NgModule({
    ...
    providers: [
        MAT_TOOLTIP_SCROLL_STRATEGY_FACTORY_PROVIDER,
        {provide: HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG, useClass: HammerGestureConfig},
        ...
    ]
})
```